# How to increase the size of a SymbolIcon in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a button that I want to use to launch video playback, so it should look like a "Play" button. The button will be fairly large on screen. This is what I have so far:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PlayButton}">
    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Play"/>                                
</Button>
```

The PlayButton resource defines a MinHeight and MinWidth of 200px. The problem with this is that the play icon is very small, in the order of 16px or so. How can I make it larger?     I tried setting FontSize="200" in the Button declaration, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it worked for me and might work for you:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PlayButton}">
    <Viewbox MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="200">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Play"/>                                
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Comment: This works a treat in the latest UWP, I think it is the best way to do this.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @mike I'm getting the error: `SymbolIcon is not supported in WPF`. Is there any workaround for your suggestion in `WPF`?

Answer (score 10):

You could use a `TextBlock` with `FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Text="&#57602;"` and then setting `FontSize` works. If you look at the [`Symbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx) values - you can see the 57602 is the value of the `Play` symbol enum which corresponds to the character code in "Segoe UI Symbol". More typically these values are written with their hex values as in `Text="&#xE102;"`, but the decimal is easier to find if you look at that enum's documentation.

Comment: I found it useful to also set `OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings"` to get rid of empty space on either side of the glyph, making it easier to align in my layout.

Comment: It seems that one difference this approach has to using `SymbolIcon` is that on Windows 10 systems, it won't automatically use the newer _Segoe MDL2 Assets_ font.

Answer (score 6):

Another easy solution is to use RenderTransform. E.g.

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Previous" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  >
    <AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
          <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1.4" ScaleY="1.4"/>
    </AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
</AppBarButton>
```

Comment: The transform doesn't appear to be applied to the AppBarButton when running the Phone project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button.Content>
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SymbolTextBlockStyle}"
                 Text="&#xE102;"/>
</Button.Content>

<Style x:Key="SymbolTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
</Style>
```

You can insert the icon as a text block, and change the font size, color and much more

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.